# When does the Stream subscriber cancel the subscription?

Tags: scala, stream, akka, akka-stream

I am using **Akka Stream 2.5.5**. I have a `Stream` where:

- An actor is acting as a Source to the Stream. I did this using: `Source.actorPublisher`
- The Stream has multiple stages. In case of `map`,`collect` etc, I have used [Recover](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/stream/stream-error.html#recover) to handle exceptions that might occur .
- For handling errors from [mapAsync()](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/stream/stream-error.html#errors-from-mapasync) , I am using supervision strategy as : `.withAttributes(supervisionStrategy(resumingDecider)))`

Now, when I run the Stream, I am getting `akka.stream.actor.ActorPublisherMessage.Cancel` propagated to my Source Actor. From the docs:

```
/**
   * This message is delivered to the [[ActorPublisher]] actor when the stream subscriber cancels the
   * subscription.
   */
  final case object Cancel extends Cancel with NoSerializationVerificationNeeded
  sealed abstract class Cancel extends ActorPublisherMessage
```

Surprisingly, there is no any `Exception` thrown at any `stage` in the Stream. So, I am failing to understand *`why the stream subscriber cancels the subscription`*. So, I am unable to find out the exact `Cause` or `Error` on why my Stream is failing.

Any insights and reasoning on this scenario will be extremely helpful.

Comment: You described everything but the `Sink`.  It would be easier to help if you also showed the code for the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the cause by using the `recover stage` as the last stage of my stream. Previously, I was using multiple `recover` stages after each stage of my stream where I was logging the errors and simply passing the last desired value downstream.

Now, I use only one `recover stage` at the end of my stream which looks like below:

```
.recover {
          case e =>
            println("****************************")
            println("Throwing Exception. Cause: "+e.getMessage)
            println("****************************")
            throw e
        }
```

After adding this, actual Exception was thrown and I found the actual cause. In my case, one of the stage had the code which threw that exception.